# How to export into a jar that runs on external tools?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I need to export my project into a .jar, turns out in order to run it I use an external tool which I specified in "External Tools Configurations". If I run the .java in "Run As- Java Application" the application doesn't work correctly. I need to know how can I export my project so that I get a single .jar which runs with the run configuration of the external tool.

I am working in the Eclipse IDE Indigo.

Please check the image: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6IPu.gif)

Answer (score 1):

You can create executable .Jar file using eclipse, just use following steps,

- Go to File Menu, Select "Export" option,
- Following dialogbox will appear,
- Select "Runnable Jar File" option in it.
- Click Next.
- Select Launch Configuration
- Click Finish.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately there is no Launch configuration option for the external tools. So I left the defaults, which shares name with the .java. When I ran the .jar the program was running as if it was launched with the regular java application. I added an image which I hope clarifies what I am trying to achieve.